# How to fix "Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt" error

Tags: android-studio

While setting up the Flutter development environment in Android Studio, I was faced with the error in the title.

I created a Flutter application project and tried to debug it on android emulator and got the error as shown in the attached picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsC7A.png)

The Pixel 6 emulator is working correctly, Target is Android 12.0, API Level is 31.

I checked the build.gradle file in root>android>app folder to confirm the minSDKVersion, targetSdkVersion. But the error did not still resolve...

I attached the build.gradle file below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.first_app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.first_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this, 

in defaultConfig 
use these values

        minSdkVersion 26
        compileSdkVersion 33
        targetSdkVersion 31

hope that will work for you